# How do I disable iTunes Home Sharing without deauthorizing the wrong computer?

Tags: itunes

A friend guessed my iTunes password and turned on Home Sharing through iTunes.  I unknowingly logged in looking for some information, this re-associated my password with my friend's email address.  I found some information about de-authorizing a computer, but it looks like this would remove my access to my iTunes account, not my friend's.  Please, can anyone help me fix this issue?

Comment: You call that a friend... ;-))

Answer (score 1):

You can just de-authorize all computers, and then re-authorize your own computer.

Answer (score 0):

if you go to the advanced tab you can deactivate all home sharing.